# Pandas map with dictionary: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to map a column with a dictionary with Pandas 0.25.2. The intent is to replace each occurrence of any dictionary key in the column with the corresponding dictionary value. The target/output column does not exist in the DataFrame. I've tried to pre-set the target column to `np.nan` to no avail.

```
In [252]: df.index.is_unique
Out[252]: True

In [253]: df.columns.is_unique
Out[253]: True

In [255]: 'hq_location' in df.columns
Out[255]: False

addresses = dict()
# .. populate the dict ..
df['hq_location'] = df['Headquarters Location'].map(addresses)

...

InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: This is a valid workaround but I don't understand why it's necessary: `map(addresses.get, na_action='ignore')`

Comment: Is "addesses" just a typo here of "add**r**esses" or is it in the code itself? And it looks like you have N/A values in 'Headquarters Location' column, so the `dictionary` returns an error that `map` catches and throws its own error.

Comment: @Aryerez Yes, that's a typo. There is indeed NAN values. According to the docs for `Series.map`: `When arg is a dictionary, values in Series that are not in the dictionary (as keys) are converted to NaN.`